# Windows Mobile Device Screen Display Problem

Tags: windows-mobile

I have developed a Windows Mobile application using Visual Studio 2008 in C#. The interface is displayed properly in Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator. However when I deploy into device, the interface is not displayed properly. It does not auto fit to screen size. List view, progress bar, picture box and etc are used in the interface.

May I know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The "Windows Mobile 6 Professional Emulator" has a low-resolution display.  Your physical device might be a hi-res device, which might explain the rendering difference.  There is a "Windows Mobile 6 VGA Profesional Emulator" which has a high-res display - try running your app on the `VGA` emulator and see if it renders correctly.  Note: you probably don't want to use the `Square` emulators - these have pretty non-standard square screens.

If this is the issue, try setting the [`AutoScaleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on the Windows Mobile `Form` to `AutoScaleMode.Dpi` rather than `AutoScaleMode.Inherit`.  This is a property of the `Form` itself (you'll need to set this on every form in your app, unless you have some sort of inheritance structure setup).  The `Dpi` setting tells Windows Mobile to autoscale the form based on screen resolution.  The default setting `Inherit` tells the form to use the `AutoScaleMode` of its parent form, but if it doesn't have a parent, it defaults to no scaling.